# How do you integrate the C# Scripting API (csi.exe) with a host program?

Tags: c#, csi

For the sake of simplicity, if I have a game engine.  Use C# compiled.  How would I call a C# *script* using the csi.exe (or some other method).  How do I use the C# Scripting API in another program like Lua?

Edit:  Clarification.  I do not want to call C#'s csi.exe from Lua.  I want to call the csi.exe from a compiled program, whether that is C# (a compiled C# program), C++, or something else.  I did not mean it to sound like calling the Scripting API from Lua.  I mean like other programs use Lua.  That is how I want to use the C# Scripting API.  I am mostly interested in how to call the C# script from a compiled C# program.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to expose at least some of your game engine's functionality to C# scripts?

Comment: @zneak Yes.  That was the only example I could think of.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough around the matter to post a complete solution, but you may want to look in the direction of `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use csi.exe, you can actually compile and execute C# within your application (with context to your solution objects, classes and methods).

I haven't found some real documentation about it beside some [blog posts](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20scripting).

The main methods you should look at are in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting`.

Look over `CSharpScript.RunAsync` and `CSharpScript.EvaluteAsync`, these two would compile and execute a given C# script, with syntax similar to the csi.exe syntax.

For example if you wish the user to enter some code and expect this code to return some string while exposing the user to the `MyClass`assembly:

```
private async void CompileAndExecuteLine(string userCode)
    {
        string output = "";
        ScriptOptions scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(typeof(MyClass).Assembly);

        try
        {
            output = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(userCode, scriptOptions);
        }
        catch (CompilationErrorException cee)
        {
            string message = "You got errors:" + "\r\n";
            foreach (Diagnostic dia in cee.Diagnostics)
            {
                message += dia.ToString() + "\r\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Compilation Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

In this example the code you enter must return a string (need to end with `return someString;`), you can call any class and method from the referenced assembly, and even declare your own classes within the `userCode` (but no namespaces).

If you wish to have some terminal environment (=always return some string), consider to manipulate the user defined code before execution.

Answer (score 0):

To call into csi.exe from lua, you would use

```
os.execute("c:\\<csi.exe location>\csi.exe myscript.csx")
```

If you need to pass input arguments then

```
os.execute("c:\\<csi.exe location>\csi.exe myscript.csx myArg")
```

Inside your myscript.csx file you can access the arguments via

```
Args[0] ... Args[n]
```

Comment: I may not have explained it, but I want to call c#'s csi.exe from something compiled, maybe another c# compiled program, or c++ or something else.  I do not wan to call the csi from lua.  Lua was an example of where this is done with other engines.

Comment: With your new information all I can say is that it will be language dependent.  In a C# application you could use ```System.Diagnostics.Process.Start``` to start csi.exe. Since csi.exe doesn't have an output stream if you want it to be interactive you may have to use something like a file or shared memory. Sorry my C++ is out of date and I don't remember off the top of my head how to do it in that language.